# Is evolution of gametangia in land plants and charophyceae convergent?

Tags: evolution, botany

Is the presence of [gametangia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gametangium) in both [land plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embryophyte) and [charophyceae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charophyceae) a result of convergent evolution or are they of the same origin (and have been lost in other types of algea)?